# How many times a team has won a playoffs series without scoring a power play goal?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

The Montreal Canadiens beat the Pittsburgh Penguins 3 - 1 in their best of 5 series of qualifying round of the 2019-20 Stanley Cup playoffs. The heavy underdogs pulled of the upset without scoring a single power play goal.

Which teams have managed to win a Stanley cup playoff series (at least a best of 5) without scoring any power play goals?

Comment: If I find time i'll investigate more, but I suspect the list is quite long - you may want to narrow this some.  PPG are rare enough that I suspect it's not that uncommon, especially in years past when scoring was harder to come by, and I'm not sure an answer with 100 games in it or something is a great idea.

Comment: I think it's already a rare occurrence for a team to win a series without any PPG. You'd have to outplay another playoff team 3 or 4 games without getting a PPG (and the games in the series which you lose). Teams that struggle in PPs don't tend to do well in the playoffs (general statement, doesn't apply to all teams obviously).

Comment: I don't disagree, but 'rare' in the context of the NHL playoffs, which has... thousands? ... of series in the original 6 - now era, might still come up a lot :) And... Blackhawks fan here, very familiar with teams being quite terrible at powerplay and still winning  (see: 2013 Cup finals... almost on this list!)

Comment: Leaving this here so I have it... to do this programatically, start with the year pages https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_2013.html and find the league playoff series table, hit the View Matchup page, find the winning team, and then find the Team Total line in the Series Stats for that team, to get their PPG count.

Comment: Man, this is begging for someone to write a bot/scrapper for it, if I get too bored I'll do it. But that being said, there's lots of sports to watch now and I'm starting a new job next week, so prob won't happen for months. 3 Months ago I would've spent all my time on this.

Comment: Back in the day, the playoffs didn't have that many teams, and so not as many rounds either. If we implement a bot, no need to worry about how many times it's happened

Comment: Yes, I was planning to scrape that info - hence the comment with the instructions so I don't forget later :)

Comment: Sooo guess who ended up scrapping for it, the same day he said he prob wouldn't do it for months??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scraping off [Hockey Reference](https://www.hockey-reference.com), I found 61 instances where a team didn't score a Power Play Goal (PPG) since 1934. Hockey Reference only shows PPGs starting 1934, hence why the data starts from then. Also, I've only looked at series, where the winning team won 3 or more games to satisfy the best-of-5 or higher criteria of the question.

As of the end of the 2020-2021 season, there have been 16 teams winning such playoff series (26.23% of all such occurrences), 3 of which happened this season! Half of the series were best-of-7, other half were best-of-5. Here are the series:

- [1934 NHL Stanley Cup Final](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1934-chicago-black-hawks-vs-detroit-red-wings-stanley-cup-final.html): Chicago Black Hawks defeat Detroit Red
  Wings 3-1
- [1937 NHL Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1937-detroit-red-wings-vs-montreal-canadiens-semi-finals.html): Detroit
  Red Wings defeat Montreal Canadiens 3-2
- [1938 NHL Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1938-boston-bruins-vs-toronto-maple-leafs-semi-finals.html): Toronto Maple Leafs
  defeat Boston Bruins 3-0
- [1942 NHL Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1942-new-york-rangers-vs-toronto-maple-leafs-semi-finals.html): Toronto Maple Leafs defeat New York
  Rangers 4-2
- [1972 NHL Quarter-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1972-chicago-black-hawks-vs-pittsburgh-penguins-quarter-finals.html):
  Chicago Black Hawks defeat Pittsburgh Penguins 4-0
- [1980 NHL Quarter-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1980-new-york-rangers-vs-philadelphia-flyers-quarter-finals.html): Philadelphia
  Flyers defeat New York Rangers 4-1
- [1984 NHL Smythe Division Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1984-edmonton-oilers-vs-winnipeg-jets-smythe-division-semi-finals.html): Edmonton Oilers defeat
  Winnipeg Jets 3-0
- [1984 NHL Patrick Division Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1984-new-york-islanders-vs-new-york-rangers-patrick-division-semi-finals.html):
  New York Islanders defeat New York Rangers 3-2
- [1985 NHL Smythe Division Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1985-edmonton-oilers-vs-los-angeles-kings-smythe-division-semi-finals.html): Edmonton Oilers
  defeat Los Angeles Kings 3-0
- [1988 NHL Adams Division Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1988-boston-bruins-vs-montreal-canadiens-adams-division-finals.html): Boston Bruins defeat
  Montreal Canadiens 4-1
- [2003 NHL Western Conference Quarter-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2003-detroit-red-wings-vs-mighty-ducks-of-anaheim-western-conference-quarter-finals.html): Mighty Ducks of
  Anaheim defeat Detroit Red Wings 4-0
- [2011 NHL Eastern Conference Quarter-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2011-boston-bruins-vs-montreal-canadiens-eastern-conference-quarter-finals.html):
  Boston Bruins defeat Montreal Canadiens 4-3
- [2013 NHL Eastern Conference Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2013-boston-bruins-vs-pittsburgh-penguins-eastern-conference-finals.html): Boston
  Bruins defeat Pittsburgh Penguins 4-0
- [2020 NHL Eastern First Round](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2020-columbus-blue-jackets-vs-tampa-bay-lightning-eastern-first-round.html): Tampa Bay
  Lightning defeat Columbus Blue Jackets 4-1
- [2020 NHL Qualifying Round](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2020-columbus-blue-jackets-vs-toronto-maple-leafs-qualifying-round.html): Columbus Blue Jackets defeat Toronto Maple Leafs 3-2
- [2020 NHL Qualifying Round](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2020-montreal-canadiens-vs-pittsburgh-penguins-qualifying-round.html): Montreal Canadiens defeat
  Pittsburgh Penguins 3-1

*Bonus*: There have been 5 series where neither team scored a PPG:

- [1934 NHL Stanley Cup Final](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1934-chicago-black-hawks-vs-detroit-red-wings-stanley-cup-final.html): Chicago Black Hawks defeat Detroit Red
  Wings 3-1
- [1937 NHL Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1937-detroit-red-wings-vs-montreal-canadiens-semi-finals.html): Detroit
  Red Wings defeat Montreal Canadiens 3-2
- [1938 NHL Semi-Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1938-boston-bruins-vs-toronto-maple-leafs-semi-finals.html): Toronto Maple Leafs
  defeat Boston Bruins 3-0
- [1988 NHL Adams Division Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/1988-boston-bruins-vs-montreal-canadiens-adams-division-finals.html): Boston Bruins defeat
  Montreal Canadiens 4-1
- [2013 NHL Eastern Conference Finals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2013-boston-bruins-vs-pittsburgh-penguins-eastern-conference-finals.html): Boston
  Bruins defeat Pittsburgh Penguins 4-0